# Failed to find link or button, rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using rspec to test my rails app and i have some trouble with click on in Capybara:
This is my spec:

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
require 'user'
require 'rails_helper'
describe User do
  before(:all) do
    shop = Shop.create(:shop_no => '2401', :shop_name => 'Yamaha')
    link = Link.create(:name => "location")
    @agent = User.create(:user_id => '1992112-1234', :password=> 'sa1234',
    :name => 'sa1234', :uid=> '0000000000002',
    :shop_no => '2401')
    login(@agent)
  end
...
  it "logout sucess in menu" do
    visit "welcome/menu"
    click_on('Button')
  end
...
```

And, this is my page where i looking for 'Button'

```
<div class="medium-4 medium-centered row" align="center" style="padding: 45px; padding-top: 0px">
    <div class="medium-10 medium-centered columns">
        <div class="medium-10 medium-centered row" style="margin-bottom: 8px">
            <a href="save" id="but" class="button expand" />発注</a>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #008cba; border-right: 0px; border-radius: 5px 5px; margin-bottom: 8px">
            <div class="columns small-2" style="margin-top: .9em">
                仕入
            </div>
            <div class="small-10 columns">
                <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 8px">
                    <a href="save" class="button expand"/>Button</a>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="save" class="button expand"/>直接仕入</a>
                </div>
            </div>      
      </div>
</div>
```

When i run spec, i have this error:
[image]

Please! help me to fix that :)

Comment: This could be because the page you are visiting by `visit "welcome/menu"` isn't loaded yet. Try to insert `sleep(5)` after `visit` string.

Answer (score 0):

There is click_button option you can try that also, i hope this link would be helpful for you http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara